# Clean up JSON (unwanted \ and ") within values in Python

Tags: python, json, escaping, backslash, data-cleaning

My JSON file looks something like below:

```
"appInfo": {
    "name": "\fÞ\r ",
    "version": " a\\r ",
    "appName": "\fÞ\"",
    "appId": 1234
},
```

Note:

- I have accented characters in values (Chinese, German etc)
- What I have shown above is only a part of JSON record
- There are miltiple json records in a file (1 JSON record in 1 line)

What I am having to do:

1. Remove all occurrences of `\r` `\t` `\f` from JSON values
2. Keep all the remaining `\` intact, but just escape them adding one more `\` before that only if they are not already escaped
3. If there is any double quotes within values which are not escaped, they need to be escaped too
4. See below for expected output in a file

`"appInfo": {
    "name": "Þ ",
    "version": " a\\ ",
    "appName": "Þ\"",
    "appId": 1234
},`

I am having to write a Python script for this, Any pointers would be helpful.

Thank you ! Happy holidays

Answer (score 0):

There is a logical flaw in your question.

If `"\fÞ\r "` must become `"Þ "` then `" a\\r "` must become `" a\\r "` if you want to keep all actual `\` with a `\` before them. Because then the escaped `\` (being `\\` in your input) becomes `\\` in your output, and the `r` has to stay a standalone `r` in the output. Thus giving you `" a\\r "`.

Having `" a\\r "` becoming `" a\\ "` makes no sense in this context.

I understand that for you, `\\r` means `standalone \ then \r` but speaking in the language of regex, it is not the case. It instead means `escaped \` then standalone (and not escaped) `r`.

Comment: I realize my comments were confusing, apologies.This is the scenario:I am loading data in JSON format as shown above in HDFS & then processing it further using HIVE,now Hive treats `\r` as new line char ir-respective of where ever it appears(even within double quotes of a JSON value).Thus the loads fail. For eg. `"\fÞ\r` would fail and `"a\\r"` would be processed since `\` before `r` is escaped.  I would want to clean up in a way that all my records are processed (even at the cost of removing some characters)  Hope I am able to explain neatly. Furthermore thanks for looking into this !